# Stop "File not found in root path, do you want to change root?" message

Tags: package

When using Spacemacs and neotree, I often see this message pop up

```
File not found in root path, do you want to change root? (y or n)
```

If I say `y`, it moves neotree to the directory of whatever buffer I was on at the time that it popped up. However, I rarely want to do this and would rather not see the message. Is there a flag I can disable to achieve this?

---

This message is printed by the Neotree package [[reference](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/blob/543b75943b573d9c8b3a22476bdabb331306fd68/neotree.el#L1612)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the below variable in your .emacs to avoid the confirmation message.

```
(setq neo-force-change-root t)
```